# Round number up until it is evenly divisible into another number - not limited to integers

Tags: sql, sql-server

As an example I have two numbers (40.25 & 1.88001).  In reality the two numbers could be any number with up to five decimal places.  However, the second number will always be <= the first number.

I need to round 1.88001 up until it is evenly divisible into 40.25. I need to find a factor of 40.25 that is greater than and closest to 1.88001.

I need to maintain the decimal precision if necessary, meaning I can't just round up to the nearest integer unless a whole number is indeed the closest factor.

I have found other solutions/questions that are similar but have found none that are applicable and/or SQL related.

So far I have a brute force solution that is too slow to be of any real use:

```
    Declare @SheetLength as money = 40.25
    Declare @PartLength as money = 1.88001

    WHILE @SheetLength % @PartLength > 0
        BEGIN
        @PartLength = @PartLength + .00001
        END

    Select @PartLength
```

There must be a faster/more efficient way to do this ...

Comment: Given your examples, what is the expected result? I've got no idea at the moment.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever For 40.25 / Y = X, where Y is an integer, and X is a decimal greater than or equal to 1.88001, OP wants to get the value of X that is closest to 1.88001. Given this example and Gordon's answer, that would be 40.25 / 21 = 1.9166666....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean "round up"? The simplest solution is to take the ratio of the two numbers, take the floor, and divide that into the larger number:

```
select @SheetLength / floor(@SheetLength / @PartLength)
```

For your example, this gives 1.91666667.